# How to edit a customtkinter's Textbox's lines?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

The question relates to changing the fonts of different rows in a customtkinter textbox object. With tag_configure it gives an error that it's not allowed due to scaling.

```
self.test = CTkTextbox(scrollable_frame.scrollable_frame, corner_radius=20, width=400, height=100,
                           border_width=2, bg_color=colur2, border_color=colur3, fg_color=colur2, text_color=colur3)
self.test.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")
self.test.insert(tk.END, "News\n", "1")
self.test.insert(tk.END, "Something about news comes here...\n", "2")
self.test.tag_configure("1", font=("Arial", 16))
self.test.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug or limitation in customtkinter. I recommend that you [edit] your question to include the complete error.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't run your code in the current form.

Answer (score 0):

So when using CustomTkinker you are not allowed the change the font per line.

You can either use the Text Object from Tkinker like such:

```
from tkinter import Text, END, Tk, DISABLED

# Create the main window
root = Tk()

txt = Text(root,width=34,height=20,background='#d9d9d9')
txt.place(x=0,y=0)
txt.insert(END, "News\n", "1")
txt.insert(END, "Something about news comes here...\n", "2")
txt.tag_configure(1, font=("Arial", 16))
txt.configure(state=DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```

Or use Labels and make your own Textbox by looping through the text. Hope this helps

And the Third option edit the CustomTkinker API ( with adverse effects and cation anyone changing the API ) However by removing the 'IF' statement you can bypass the AttributeError.

```
    def tag_config(self, tagName, **kwargs):
    if "font" in kwargs:
        raise AttributeError("'font' option forbidden, because would be incompatible with scaling")
    return self._textbox.tag_config(tagName, **kwargs)
```